# Cordova - Android - Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle

Making an android project with cordova, when I try to making a build, it failed with this issue:

```
execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0
```

These are my versions:

```
Cordova: 10.0.0
Android Platform: 10.1.2 
Gradle: 7.1.1
```

I am absolutely sure that Gradle is installed when I install the Android platform (and it is out of my control) and that everything was working fine until 1 month ago ... and I have not changed anything

How I can fix this issue???
Have I to update Gradle? How?
Have I to update the project? How?

it's very strange ... and frustrating

Comment: same issue in cordova 11. I see that the latest version of gradle is 7.5.1. I'll try to update it to see. BTW, support of cordova is declining obviously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating gradle solves the problem.

There are different ways to update the gradle, as explained in their official website: https://gradle.org/install/

*Assuming that you are a windows user*:

Downloading binary files of gradle and extracting the folder to the directory "c:/gradle" is enough.

- Download binary files of gradle for the next version
- Update path of `gradle` in PATH variable in your computer
  [image]
- You should define another variable as follows:
  [image]
- Variable name should be the same and its value should be the same with the one you use. While creating your cordova environment, this url is being used.
- Save and restart your IDE's or CLI windows
- test it out like ´gradle -v´ and you should see the active version of gradle in your system.
- Be prepared to the new problems in your cordova environment because you have a upgraded gradle now

Comment: I upgraded Gradle to the most recent version as of today (7.5.1) and I still get this error.

Is it possible that somehow my Cordova is still pointing to the old version of Gradle?  I'm on a Mac.  Do I need to change that somewhere?  

From a command prompt in my project folder, when I type "gradle -v" it does give me the correct version (7.5.1).  So I'm really stuck now as to what to do...

Comment: My cordova keeps downloading version 7.1.1 of gradle.  How do I get it to stop that?!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I've reverted to `cordova-android` version `9.1.0`. I've no idea, as of now, why `cordova-android` version `10` points to `gradle`, which as of now isn't possible to download...